# Json Response Is Not Coming Full In Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

Hi below is the code I have written which returns Incomplete json result with 50 records only. Same code in console application returns 250 records. Can you please tell what I am doing wrong here.

```
using (var handler = new HttpClientHandler() { CookieContainer = new CookieContainer() })
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient(handler) { BaseAddress = new Uri(clientDetails.endPointDetails[0].HttpUrl) })
    {   
        var body = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
        
        clientDetails.endPointDetails[0].clientApiParameters.ForEach(x =>
        {
            string[] param = x.Parameters.Split('=');
            body.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>( param[0], param[1]));
        });
        
        HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, clientDetails.endPointDetails[0].HttpUrl);
        
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("multipart/form-data"));
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + clientDetails.endPointDetails[0].Token);
        
        client.MaxResponseContentBufferSize = 9999999;
        client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(10000);
        //HttpResponseMessage response = client.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead).Result;
        
        var res = await client.PostAsync("", new FormUrlEncodedContent(body));
        
        if (res.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            
            string exec = await res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            ExplaraData responseJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExplaraData>(exec);
            int result = BusinessModel.SaveClientRequestLog(clientDetails.ClientId, exec);
            if (result <= 0)
            {
                message.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.NoContent;
                return message;
            }
            BusinessModel.SaveExplaraData(responseJson);
            message.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK;
        }
        else
        {
            message.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.NoContent;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The API response is probably paginated with a page size of 50. It also may have to do with the default limit parameter on your API call.

Look into the documentation for how to request another page of results, or how to change the limit in your request.

Comment: yes you are right...!! parameters are only not taking allRecords as yes. Thanks for the information